# Odd behavior with geom_raster

Tags: r, ggplot2

There is an odd behavior when the `x` or  `y`-data are not equidistantly spaced:

```
dat <- expand.grid( x = 1:10, y = seq(1, 10, by = 3))
dat$z <- rnorm( nrow(dat) )
ggplot( data = dat, aes( x = x, y = y, fill = z ) ) +
  geom_raster()
```

[image]

```
dat <- rbind( data.frame( x = 1:10, y = 0, z = rnorm(10) ), dat )
ggplot( data = dat, aes( x = x, y = y, fill = z ) ) +
  geom_raster()
```

[image]

```
dat <- rbind( data.frame( x = 15, y = c(0,1,3,7,10), z = rnorm(10) ), dat )
ggplot( data = dat, aes( x = x, y = y, fill = z ) ) +
  geom_raster()
```

[image]

Is this a bug? A feature? Any suggested workarounds to avoid the unfilled spaces in the latter two examples?

Comment: `geom_raster()` is just doing what you are asking it to do. From `?geom_raster`: `This is a special case of geom_tile where all tiles are the same size.`

Comment: @Pascal `geom_tile()` produces the same result, btw.

Comment: with `geom_tile` you can map `height=y` to make things better